# Use WHERE condition in SQL where parameters can be NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Good day everyone.

I wrote a stored procedure which takes some parameters in input (INT, VARCHAR, Date)
All of them are NULLable.

I'm having problem when setting the condition:

```
@day DATE NULL
@age INT NULL
@nome VARCHAR(50) NULL

SELECT *
    FROM [table]
    WHERE   (ISNULL(@day, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OR [table].[day] = @day)
        AND (ISNULL(@age, 0) = 0 OR [table].age = @age)
        AND (LEN(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)),'')) = 0 OR [table].name LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)) + '%')
```

The conditions for `age` and `name` work just fine.

`day` is giving me some trouble. If I use `NULL` in place of the parameter in the condition `(ISNULL(NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OR [table].[day] = @day)` it works and I get all the content of the table in respect to the other conditions, otherwise, with `@day` set as `NULL`, the query doesn't return anything.

Comment: A very common question that has many discussions. Erland runs through various methods [here - dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in this expression:

```
ISNULL(@day, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

you expect that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the same value in both sides, but this is not what happens.
The value returned by the *right* side of the equality is evaluated once for the whole statement while the value returned by the *left* side is evaluated for every row of the table since it contains a variable which may (or not) have changed.
 
So the timestamps are different as you can see if you execute this:

```
declare @day date = null;
select 1
where isnull(@day, current_timestamp) = current_timestamp
```

which returns nothing.
But if instead of the variable you use `null`:

```
select 1
where isnull(null, current_timestamp) = current_timestamp
```

then both sides are evaluated once and for the whole statement and the result is `true` so you get results.

But if you store the returned value of `current_timestamp` in a variable, like this:

```
declare @currentday date = current_timestamp;
declare @day date = null;
select 1
where isnull(@day, @currentday) = @currentday
```

then you can be sure that you are comparing the same timestamp and you will get results.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d892dd753b5f1f9eb402d97c5fcbbd3d).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your answer is because of the non-deterministic nature of the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function. The values are being calculated differently for each implementation and therfore they are not set to the same value in your comparison.

You need to compare with something deterministic - possoibly making use of the fact that the base date value is always the same

```
WHERE   ISNULL(@d, DATEADD(DAY, 0, 0)) = DATEADD(DAY, 0, 0)
```